# creating a link to the record in a completed form

Tags: google-app-maker

I am a pretty new to App Maker.  I have a form that the user completes called **CreditApplication** (it's linked datasource is also called **CreditApplication**).
This form has a Submit button. Upon submission, I want an email with a link to the record that was just completed to be emailed to another user.

I am having trouble creating this link.  I would like the link to bring the emailed user to the same record in the **CreditApplication** form. 
I have listed what I have below.

The **CreditApplication** form has a **Submit** button with the onClick set to:

```
createRequest(widget).
```

The **CreditApplication** datasource has the following code in the **onCreate** event:

```
var to = "jdoe@gmail.com";
var subject = "New Online Credit Application Submission - " + record.FirstName + " (Sales Contact: " + record.SalesContact + ")";
var msg = "A credit application has been submitted for " + record.FirstName + "." + "<br><br>";
var appUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() + '#CreditApplication?requestId=' + record._key;
msg = msg + appUrl;
MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, msg, {htmlBody: msg});
```

My client javascript code is in a library called ClientScripts and is displayed below:

```
/**
 * Replaces the url history state to reflect the changes upon navigation
 *     from a different screen.
 * @param {String} requestId - id of the selected request.
 */
function replaceUrlForReadRequest(requestId) {
  var params = {
    requestId: requestId
  };
  google.script.history.replace(null, params, app.pages.NewPage1.name);
}

/**
 * Replaces the url history state to reflect the changes upon navigation
 *     from a different screen.
 * @param {Page} page - application page to navigate.
 */
function replaceUrlForPage(page) {
  var params = {};
  google.script.history.replace(null, params, page.name);
}

/**
 * Creates a new request and redirects user to the read screen afterwards.
 * @param {Widget} submitButton - button that triggers the action.
 */
function createRequest(submitButton) {
  if (!submitButton.root.validate()) {
    return;
  }
  var NewPage1 = app.pages.NewPage1;
  submitButton.datasource.createItem(function(record) {    
    if (app.currentPage === NewPage1) {
      replaceUrlForReadRequest(record._key);     
    }
  });  
  app.showPage(NewPage1);
  replaceUrlForPage(NewPage1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a URL parameter that identifies the record before emailing the URL. When the users retrieve the page, use the parameter to adjust the query filter to load the record.

URL parameters can be added to the URL by client script:

```
 /**
 * Adds a URL parameter.
 * @param {string} name - name of the URL parameter;
 * @param {string} value - value of the URL parameter;
 */
function addUrlParameter(name, value) {
  google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
    var params = location.parameter;
    if (params[name]) {
      console.log('URL parameter already exists');
    } else {
      console.log('Adding URL parameter');
      params[name] = value;
      google.script.history.replace({}, params);
    }
  });
}
```

Here is an example of the onAttach event handler. "Project" is the name of the datasource. It uses the built-in data field "Key" to set the query filter.

```
/**
 * Loads a record based on the "key" parameter in URL.
 */
function loadPageByKey() {
  google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
    if ('key' in location.parameter) {
      var datasource = app.datasources.Project;
      datasource.query.clearFilters();
      datasource.query.filters.Key._equals = location.parameter.key;
      datasource.load(function() {
        datasource.query.clearFilters();
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general your code looks good, but...:

```js
// onCreate - actually it is onBeforeCreate
...
var appUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() +
             '#CreditApplication?requestId=' +
             record._key;
...
```

Actually, it is onBeforeCreate model event and at this moment of time '_key' property is not set yet... I have a feeling, that this issue should be addressed by App Maker in the nearest time.

Meanwhile... you can either adjust your app workflow or use some other field for navigation. For instance you can generate id for new records...

```js
// onCreate - workaround for missing onAfterCreate model event
...
record.UniqueId = customFunctionToGenerateUniqueId();

var appUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() +
             '#CreditApplication?requestId=' +
             record.UniqueId;
...
```